# Outlook Exchange integration in custom UI

Tags: outlook, angular5

We have to integrate calendar feature of outlook exchange  in our application, need to customize the UI for meeting room booking.

One way will be to use via registering the app in Azure AD and call the Graph API's for accessing data.
Can we access these API's without registering the app in Azure AD?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot access Graph APIs without registering your application.  The registration manifest declares how your app will authenticate against Graph, its web server location and which resources it requires access to.  Without this mechanism anybody can write code to delete all of your email.

Comment: Thanks Eric, one more question I have  Can we create a meeting room using graph API's?

Comment: Unfortunately you currently cannot do that